# Is it necessary to use UML diagram prior to php programing?

Tags: php, uml

I'm going to develop a small wordpress plugin in PHP. IS it necessary to create UML to create a good application. I think it as waste of time for small plugins. But in my plugin there are actor like visitor and admin role can take place. There can also be interaction between other author(actors in case of uml). Is UML is necessary here?

Is it necessary to be a professional?

Comment: You're asking for opinions. Do you draw up formal blueprints and run your plants past the municipal planning commission every time you want to nail two boards together? Feel free to if that's how you get your kicks. For "small" projects, it'd be a massive waste of time.

Comment: If you would set the question telling us what priorities and tasks do you have, and asking for what modelling diagrams will be useful for what reasons and on what stages, and what are your problems in using and understanding them, there could be some more fruitful discussion. Try to be maximally concrete.

Comment: I got you, it will be waste of time! thanks@Marc B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not.  UML is only a tool for planning.

The only things required to develop a small wordpress plugin are
A Wordpress environment (LAMP, MAMP, ETC), access to that environment (Control Panel,FTP, SSH, Local FileSystem, ETC), and a bit of knowledge (PHP, WordPress).

Although planning is useful and can help you stay focused on the task at hand it certainly is not uncommon for professionals to forgo formalized planning and 'knock it out'

Comment: Fully agree with the answer! To much planning on a small project can actually kill your productivity.

Comment: I have knowledge in php,jquery,css,core java,bit mysql. I develope wordpress plugins. So without UML can i say, am a professional software developer? @Marc B

Comment: If you get paid for your work you are a professional.  
Clients will eventually ask you about process and quality assurance , but they are tools to the end-goal.